# roscanopen SDO or PDO for service calls?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-canopen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If i have an object mapped to a PDO in the canopen EDS and then i go to use the ros-canopen service "set_object" to modify its value, does ros-canopen use SDO or PDO to modify this value in the object dictionary of my device?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303577/roscanopen-sdo-or-pdo-for-service-calls?/) by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have mapped the object to a RPDO (of the device), it will be used to set the value. Otherwise SDO.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on 2018-09-18**:
awesome. on another note. i very much admire the software acrhitecture used in ros-canopen. I am interested in learning a bit more and have some questions. Can i contact you in private with some questions? I know this isnt the appropriate place to ask but i dont know how else i would contact you lol

**Comment by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on 2018-09-18**:
my email is jd224234@dal.ca, shoot me an email if this is a possibility

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PDOs are used for fast communication and are sent cyclically while SDOs are not cyclic. PDOs should be used for sending real-time data and SDOs for configuration settings and services. Though PDO has higher priority than SDO but based on data type, a selection can be made. For service calls, SDOs can be used.

---

Originally posted by [Ishu Goel](https://answers.ros.org/users/44217/ishu-goel/) with karma: 11 on 2019-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1